How to set CSS attributes for one element on the basis of other element's class
I am working with React and CSS. I wanted to set "background-color":"yellow" on selector 2 (tr#selector2), if selector 1 (div.selector1) is having "show" class:
div.selector1.show

And wanted to set "background-color":"red" on selector 2 (tr#selector2), if selector 1 (div.selector1) is having "hide" class-
div.selector1.hide

Note: Selector 1 and Selector 2 both are not siblings. Both are dynamic elements in html.


<div>
  <div class="selector1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
        <div class="div5">
          <div class="div6"></div>
          <div class="div7"></div>
          <div class="div8">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="selector2"></tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If you are asking how to do this using CSS only, without additional JavaScript - then you need to show us your HTML structure, because if & how this will be possible, depends on that.

Please enhance the demo I created to add the classes you've described and add some CSS to show your attempt.

If the structure is as shown it in terms of the juxtaposition of selector1 and div2 then you can select using the adjacent sibling combinator (+):


<style>
  .selector1.show+.div2 .selector2 {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  
  .selector1.hide+.div2 .selector2 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div class="selector1 show"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
        <div class="div5">
          <div class="div6"></div>
          <div class="div7"></div>
          <div class="div8">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="selector2">
                  <td>selector2</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



If the structure is more general, in that selector1 and div2 are not in any sort of relationship (but selector2 is still within div2) then you can select using :has on some parent of selector1 and div2. This snippet uses body for that:


<style>
  body:has(.selector1.show) .div2 .selector2 {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  
  body:has(.selector1.hide) .div2 .selector2 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div class="selector1 show"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
        <div class="div5">
          <div class="div6"></div>
          <div class="div7"></div>
          <div class="div8">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="selector2">
                  <td>selector2</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




I would suggest some restructuring to make things much more convenient and extendable. You probably switch the classes based on a condition or something. What ever that thing is you can put in your react state and then programmatically switch classes like:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [myCond, setMyCond] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    // you need to calculate the correct value for your condition here
    setMyCond(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div class={`selector1${myCond ? ' show' : ' hide'}`}></div>
      <div class="div2">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="div3"></div>
            <div class="div4"></div>
            <div class="div5">
              <div class="div6"></div>
              <div class="div7"></div>
              <div class="div8">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr class={`selector2${myCond ? ' bg-yello' : ' bg-red'}`}></tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



You can refer the following code.  You need to check whether selector1 has class show or hide and then apply the conditions.
However, the selector2 ie empty tr element not taking style hence I have added some text.
Please let me know if you get to know the reason.


const selector1 = document.querySelector('.selector1');
const selector2 = document.querySelector('.selector2');

if (selector1.classList.contains('show')) {
    document.getElementById('selector2').innerText = 'somehow styles not applying on empty tr';
  document.getElementById('selector2').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 0)';
}

if (selector1.classList.contains('hide')) {
    document.getElementById('selector2').innerText = 'somehow styles not applying on empty tr';
  document.getElementById('selector2').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0)';
}
.selector1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

table thead tr .selector2 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
<div>
  <div class="selector1 hide"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
        <div class="div5">
          <div class="div6"></div>
          <div class="div7"></div>
          <div class="div8">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="selector2" id="selector2"></tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Hope, this helps.
